# How to delete a char image being called as a function in a loop in C?

Tags: c, function, loops

I'm creating a game. 
I have a function, which draws a character image at random locations using a loop. 
I have collision logic which all works perfectly fine. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to get the character image to delete from the game upon collision. The image is one of many of the same kind within the game display, so I specifically want to be able to delete the character image at the specific location, and decrease the stored total stored number if images of that type within the game, to return it on a scoreboard.

I've tried deleting the desired iteration of the called function in the same way you would if it was an array item, but that was just giving errors.

```
void drawEnemy(){
   drawEnemyImage(x[i], y[i], enemyImage);
}

void drawAllEnemies(){
   for(int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++){
   drawEnemy(i);
   }
}
// (i also have collision logic here but it's not needed for the problem)

void returnCollision(){
    for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++){
        if(collision() == true)
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this code, I can only presume you want to delete the enemy character image. Ok then. We would usually do something like this:

```
void deleteEnemy(int i) {
    --numEnemies;
    if (i == numEnemies) return;
    memmove(x + i, x + i + 1, (numEnemies - i) * sizeof(x[0]));
    memmove(y + i, y + i + 1, (numEnemies - i) * sizeof(y[0]));
}
```

Now the enemy in the middle of the arrays is gone. I'm assuming `x` and `y` are arrays of integers or something like that. If you have memory to free first, you would place the appropriate `free()` call before the `if`.

Please use better variables names for globals. `enemyx` and `enemyy` would be huge improvement already.

Comment: Thank you, oops i should've been more clear. x[i] and y[i] are the x and y locations of the of the [i]th enemy image.